# Are there any battery packs than can act as a UPS?

Tags: power-supply, battery

I have an external battery pack, for my phone - it charges via USB. I was thinking I could use it to power my new Pi Zero - if the power goes out - but I realised the one I have cannot be charged and provide power simultaneously.

[image: Photo of PowerBank]

I have a low budget (having just spent a lot on the Pi kit) - somewhere around $15 (£10).

Is there any hardware that can do this?

Comment: Tim, welcome to the Raspberry Pi StackExchange. As is, your question is asking for a shopping recommendation which is decidedly off topic as per the help center.

Comment: I agree with Jaconm001, that this is a shopping question, and so is off-topic. However, the Eloop E11 (be aware that there are a lot of fake copies of this particular model out there) will do what you require. In fact most power banks provide that functionality, you just seem to be unlucky with you particular powerbank.

Answer (score 1):

You could buy the Xiaomi power bank. I was able to run my raspberry pi 2 from it and it works very well. I have the 10000 mAh model. I got mine for $18 in Singapore.

Comment: Can it run the pi and be charged at the same time?

Comment: @Tim I haven't tried it with the Pi but it can charge my phone and be charged at the same time. So it should work with the pi also

Answer (score 1):

[This power bank](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00OH2FDYK) ($12, but I'm sure you can find it cheaper elsewhere) can be charged while it is powering the Pi, I've used it for some time now on my Zero. It's only 2400mah, but I know that all of the power banks made by iLive can do this because I've used almost all of them, at some point, to do this.

Comment: Hmm, nice. Unfortunately amazon doesn't have them in the UK. I'll look around!

Comment: Well, I wonder if Kohls ships to the UK? lol http://www.kohls.com/product/prd-1564069/ilive-compact-portable-power-charger.jsp